# Where are TortoiseHg extensions stored?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, perfarce

I've recently used Perfarce extension with mercurial on a linux system (Ubuntu 10.4 server) and did some modification to it's code to fit my needs.

Now, I would like to do the same on Windows 7x64 (where I installed TortoiseHg). I know tortoise Hg comes with some bundled extensions (perfarce included). I also know I can use a Mercurial.ini or hgrc file to enable extensions and specify the path to find them.

I suppose I could force a path to perfarce.py in my Mercurial.ini file (perfarce=path\to\extension) but since perfarce is already bundled with TortoiseHg installation, could I edit the bundled version? If so, where can I find it?

TIA

Alexandre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize this is not an answer to you exact question, but wouldn't it be better to stick `perfarce.py` in an hg repo of its own and point to it in your Mercurial.ini?

That way you wouldn't have to worry about it ever again, not even when you will update TortoiseHg.

**Edit**

Ok, I fired up a Windows machine.

The perfarce extension is contained in TortoiseHg\library.zip\hgext, but it's a `.pyo` file.

Frankly, I don't know if replacing the .pyo with an actual .py file would work. It probably would, since the pyo is just what the Python interpreter outputs when invoked with the `-O` flag, but hey, I don't know much about Python.

I guess that trying is the only way to know for sure.

Comment: Indeed, and you do have a point with the update part.

(I'll leave the question 'unanswered' for a few more hours so I may get an answer to the original question (for curiosity), but the update part did the job for me), thx

Comment: So basically, every extensions are in a .zip file... that does explain why windows couldn't figure where perfarce* file was... (and I didn't think it was possible to use a library within a zip file.

Comment: Actually, every Python app compiled into an .exe makes use of that library.zip file: it contains Python's standard library plus, like in this case, other relevant stuff.

Comment: But hey, do yourself a favor and don't use Windows to look for stuff, it's f*ckin' bad on so many levels it doesn't even deserve to be considered. Grab a copy of Total Commander. It can do all sorts of things when you got the hang of it (search in archives included).

Comment: Thx for the tip. My day is fisnished but I'll look into it tomorrow (Total Commander and using a modified perface). BTW, if it doesn't work to put a .py in the library.zip... I'll compile my own perfarce.py into a .pyo before replacing the existing one.

Comment: Why not? Let me know if that works. I don't think I'll ever need to do that, but who knows.

Comment: It does work. I guess it's not the best idea (since in Win7 I had to move the zip file in another directory before changing any file inside... seems windows doesn't like when we edit a zip file in a program file subdirectory...)

But anyway, thx for the help... I might not directly use this trick, but I've learned about where Python apps store theirs libraries...and about Total Commander.